# PHP Page Redirect for a Undeployed Website

Tags: php, web

As the final project in my web development class my project team is building a web page for a local gym.

We have the website set so that a sign-up page is displayed if no user is logged in, or an account page if a user is signed in.

Currently, I have the sign up form redirecting to a "creation" page, that processes the sign up request, which we again redirect to either the sign up page, if the sign up fails, or logs the user in and redirects them to the accounts page if the sign up is successful.

Because the website is not deployed, I dont have access to a URL, so I am struggling to use the header() function for the time being. Are there any alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use the `header()` function? What's the problem you are facing? Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: How are you viewing the code you have created so far, you must be running some form of web server? Maybe you just need to set up a URL variable and have it set to `localhost` for now?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ / http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/  / http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: You can use the `$_SERVER` super global to dynamical construct the sites URL, or set a constant for it.  This can't be the only url you needed for the site.  There are some security concerns with using `$_SERVER['http_host']` ect, that's why I suggest a constant too, but server it the quick and dirty way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you have some url

> Because the website is not deployed, I dont have access to a URL, so I am struggling to use the header() function for the time being. Are there any alternatives? Thanks!

Even local host, I would say instead of bandaging the issue, which is how do I make a url for a site that is not deployed.

The answer of course it to configure it.

```
if(!defined('SITE_URL')) define('SITE_URL', 'localhost');
 //or what every you use to access it now.
```

Then you can build your redirects like this

```
header("location: http://".SITE_URL.'/somepage');
```

And when the site is deployed you just set the constant to the correct domain.

Simple, and as a bonus anytime you need the domain of the site, you can just use the constant, such as for forms, links, images, whatever.

Comment: So I can use the localhost address as the URL? Is this testable on my local enviroment? Thanks!

Comment: what do you use to connect to it for your local environment?  I was just giving that as an example.  Use whatever domain you use now, and include the defining of the constant in something that always gets loaded first.  Then later you can just change the constant for publishing it. etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about redirecting the page without using php. Yes, there are number of alternatives.

1. Javascript: `window.location = "http://www.finallocation.com";`
2. Meta Tag: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://finallocation.com/" />`

If you want to redirect the page using these codes and with php. You can simply:

```
$URL="http://www.finallocation.com/";
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
```

or

```
echo '<script>window.location="http://finallocation.com"</script>';
```